# Protocol Buffers for VB6?

Tags: vb6, protocol-buffers

I can't seem to find any [libraries](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns) for using Protocol Buffers in VB6?

Is my only option to use a wrapper C# library via COM Interop?

Comment: Yes, I expect so. What did you actually do?

Comment: @MarkJ A C# wrapper library.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to write a protocol buffers library for VB6 ; it's not the friendliest language to write funky serialization code in, but it is an interesting intellectual exercise to work out how to do bit operations with the reduced operator set that VB6 hands you.

The pattern I used to use for VB6 serialization code was to implement a common interface on classes to be serialized ; you needed internal access to the instance variables because even public fields are encapsulated behind accessors by the compiler. I had a base library that declared the interfaces like this, along with some bits that managed class metadata, and you could write a number of serialization classes that understood this interface and transformed the instance variables into XML, SQL, bytes in an array, fields in a flat file, etc.

Alas, I no longer have access to this code, and the legality of sharing it would be dubious anyway.

Protocol Buffers entered the scene long after VB6 became unfashionable and you're unlikely to get a native VB6 library for them unless you pay someone or write it yourself.